# How to send commands to R in ESS

Tags: r, ess

I, an R user, decided recently to try using Emacs-ESS combo. So far I have been work in a single-window mode (C-x 1) just for text highlighting.

Now I am trying split it in two windows (C-x 3) to work on an `.R` file in the left window, and have R execute the commands in the right window. Something like this:
[image]

After selecting sections of code on the left, how can I "send" it as a command to the right? Essentially, I want the input to remain on on the left (so that I can incrementally build the code up) and the actual R output on (including error messages) the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two good options:

> `ess-eval-region-or-function-or-paragraph vis`
>    (**C-M-x**): Sends the current selected region or function or paragraph.
>
> `ess-eval-region-or-function-or-paragraph-and-step` (**C-c C-c**): Like `ess-eval-region-or-function-or-paragraph` but steps to next line of code.

Source: [ESS manual](http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#Evaluating-code).

Comment: Is something different happening if this is done on an R script inside a package? I am running this and the command is sent to the buffer, but apparently not executed. The variable does not exist in the session. There are a few `+` surrounding the code which is not what I'm used to. This only seems to happen to scripts in package R/ folders.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:
**C-c-p** to send a paragraph or region between two empty lines
**C-c-r** to send a region that has been selected and is highlighted

I prefer this way because you only need to press the Ctrl key

there are normally many ways to send code to the R console. It will take you time to realize what is best for you, or you may eventually change the key bindings.